# How do I select a subset of an array in Postgres?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Assuming I have an array in one of my postgres columns:

```
> select array[1,2,3,4];
   array   
-----------
 {1,2,3,4}
```

How do I select a subset of the items from that array, in general? For instance, if I want to select items from the `x` index to the `y` index, how would I grab the items in that range (`x` to `y`)?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING):

> **8.15.3. Accessing Arrays**
>   [...]
>   We can also access arbitrary rectangular slices of an array, or subarrays. An array slice is denoted by writing **lower-bound:upper-bound** for one or more array dimensions.
>   [...]
>   It is possible to omit the lower-bound and/or upper-bound of a slice specifier; the missing bound is replaced by the lower or upper limit of the array's subscripts.

For example:

```
=> select (array[1,2,3,4,5,6])[2:5];
   array   
-----------
 {2,3,4,5}
(1 row)

=> select (array[1,2,3,4,5,6])[:5];
    array    
-------------
 {1,2,3,4,5}
(1 row)

=> select (array[1,2,3,4,5,6])[2:];
    array    
-------------
 {2,3,4,5,6}
(1 row)

=> select (array[1,2,3,4,5,6])[:];
     array     
---------------
 {1,2,3,4,5,6}
(1 row)
```

So to get a slice from index `x` to `y` (inclusive), you'd say:

```
array_column[x:y]
```

Comment: Dose it support negative bound? like  [-2:-5]

Comment: @Wooden Depends what you expect that `-2` to do: "Subscripted assignment allows creation of arrays that do not use one-based subscripts. For example one might assign to `myarray[-2:7]` to create an array with subscript values from `-2` to `7`.". That's straight out of the documentation.

Comment: Note that `[2:]` works for taking all elements except the first one.

Comment: @StevenSoroka That's actually mentioned a couple paragraphs down in the docs but worth noting anyway. You can also say `[:5]` and `[:]`.

Comment: Also note that for sparse arrays, the slices may not return what you expect. Given an empty array of integers where we only set `arr[3] = 3` and `arr[5] = 5`, the result for `arr[1]` would be `NULL`, but the result of `arr[1:]` is `{3,NULL,5}`.