# How can i select an array into a larger array without overwriting it in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am writing some SQL code where i have a comma separated string with 3 values. I would like to transform this string into an array and write it into the first 3 elements of a larger array.

My naive approach was this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    my_string varchar := '1.0,1.1,1.2';
    target_array real[6] := '{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}';
BEGIN
    select string_to_array(my_string, ',') into target_array;
    raise notice '%', target_array;
END$$;
```

this returns `NOTICE:  {1,1.1,1.2}`

what i want is `NOTICE:  {1,1.1,1.2,0.,0.,0.}`

i tried to slice the target array `target_array[:3]` but this results in a syntax error.

So, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate `my_string` converted to an array (i.e. `my_string_array`) with a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793871/how-do-i-select-a-subset-of-an-array-in-postgres) of `target_array` that has its first elements removed.

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE 
  my_string varchar := '1.0,1.1,1.2';
  target_array real[] := '{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}';
  my_string_array real[] := string_to_array(my_string, ',');
BEGIN
  target_array := my_string_array||target_array[array_length(my_string_array,1) + 1:];
  raise notice '%', target_array;
end
$$;
```

Or you can use a loop

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE 
    my_string varchar := '1.0,1.1,1.2';
    target_array real[] := '{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}';
    my_string_array real[] := string_to_array(my_string, ',');
    i integer;
begin
    for i in 1 .. array_length(my_string_array, 1) loop
        target_array[i] := my_string_array[i];
    end loop;
    raise notice '%', target_array;
end
$$;
```

Both produce `{1,1.1,1.2,0,0,0}`.

Answer (score 1):

See if this solves your problem :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arraycalc(arrayone INT[], arraytwo INT[] )
RETURNS TEXT AS 
$body$
DECLARE 
iaReturnarray INT [] ; 
iCount INT := 1 ; 
BEGIN 

WHILE iCount <= array_length(arrayone , 1) 
LOOP 
iaReturnarray := array_append( iaReturnarray , arrayone[iCount] ); 
iCount := iCount+1 ; 
END LOOP ; 
WHILE iCount <= array_length(arraytwo , 1 )
LOOP 
iaReturnarray := array_append( iaReturnarray , arraytwo[iCount] ); 
iCount := iCount+1 ; 
END LOOP ; 

RETURN iaReturnarray::text ; 
END ; 

$body$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql ; 


SELECT arraycalc(ARRAY[1,2,3] , ARRAY[0,0,0,0,0,0])CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arraycalc(arrayone INT[], arraytwo INT[] )
RETURNS TEXT AS 
$body$
DECLARE 
iaReturnarray INT [] ; 
iCount INT := 1 ; 
BEGIN 

WHILE iCount <= array_length(arrayone , 1) 
LOOP 
iaReturnarray := array_append( iaReturnarray , arrayone[iCount] ); 
iCount := iCount+1 ; 
END LOOP ; 
WHILE iCount <= array_length(arraytwo , 1 )
LOOP 
iaReturnarray := array_append( iaReturnarray , arraytwo[iCount] ); 
iCount := iCount+1 ; 
END LOOP ; 

RETURN iaReturnarray::text ; 
END ; 

$body$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql ; 


SELECT arraycalc(ARRAY[1,2,3] , ARRAY[0,0,0,0,0,0]);
```